# Mobile access point to wired network

Tags: wireless-networking, android, hotspot

I have a situation where I'm using my mobile phone as my internet connection and connecting my WiFi enabled devices to it without problem. The problem is I have an array of devices which are ethernet only such as my my NAS and TV which i would like to connect to my mobile phone.

What device do i need? I found a solution today but was told i couldn't use it as it used as it used WPS plus it only had one ethernet port and i need at least three.

Is it a wireless access point i need if so any recommendation of one that doesn't use WPS

Answer (score 1):

You need a device which can talk to both medias - WiFi and Ethernet in same time.

If your cell phone can serve as router - than you need just WiFi access point configured on Layer 2 and on other hand connected to Layer 2 Switch where all other Ethernet devices will be connected.

If your cell phone can not be a router than WiFi access point should be configured on Layer 3 with NAT. Otherwise it is same concept.

But if you are saying you are already using cell phone for this purpose - than most likely it can be a router, so you just need FiWi access point configured as client for you cell phone WiFi. Ethernet cable from access point goes to a switch where all other Ethernet devices go as well.

I can not recommend you a particular access point - there are many of them and majority of them will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would look for a wireless router which I could wire my phone to (phone acting as modem) then use the wireless of the router to connect the other devices to.  [Here is a guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Cellular_Phone/USB_Modem_as_WAN_connection) on the subject, but gird your loins as it is a bit long and technical.

Another similar but less optimal option would be get a dual band router that is [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) compatiable (like a [DIR-825](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-825-xtreme-n-dual-band-gigabit-router)) so you could set up a wireless bridge between the phone and the router using one band (phone still acting as modem) then use the other band to connect your wireless devices to.  You could also use WDS instead of a wireless bridge if you wanted, but WDS is less efficient with your bandwidth when compared to a wireless bridge.  The difference is that when using a wireless bridge the two devices that make the bridge can only talk to each other, thus the need for dual bands.

In all cases you could then use the LAN ports of the wireless router to connect your wired clients.